# Validate a value cannot less than 0

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have this form on Yii2

```
Employee Name   : N1
Apply Date      : 2016-08-26
Start Date      : 2016-08-29
Days Leave      : 4 Days
Days Leave Left : 8
Status          : Pending
```

The result i expected is,when i input 9 days on Days Leave,the form will validate

```
"Maximum Quota is Exceeded,Cannot Input"
```

here is my Models to get Days Leave Left

```
  public function daysleaveleft($id,$year) {
        $models = Leave::find()->select(['daysleave'=>'sum(daysleave)'])->where(['EmpId' => $id,'year(startdate)'=>$year])->One();

        $setting = Setting::find()->where(['Var'=>'MaxLeave'])->One();
        return $Setting->Val - $models['daysleave'];            
    }
```

**Edited**

```
Days Leave | Days Leave Left
    0      |       12
    4      |       8
    3      |       5
    6      |      -1
```

i'm expecting the result will be like this,when user input 6,when he has 5 quota left,the form will validate.

Comment: Is the `daysleaveleft` function inside the Employee model?

Comment: no,it's inside Leave Model

Comment: Which model does the form above represent?

Comment: it's on Leave Model also,

Comment: How do you call this `daysleaveleft` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [inline validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#inline-validators).

In your rules add:

```
['field_name', 'integer', 'min' => 1],
['field_name', 'validateLeaveDays', 'when' => $this->startdate && $this->EmpId]
```

And to your `Leave` model add:

```
public function validateLeaveDaysLeft($attribute) {
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($this->startdate));
    $maxLeaveDays = $this->daysleaveleft($this->EmpId, $year);
    if ($this->$attribute < $maxLeaveDays) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Maximum Quota is Exceeded,Cannot Input');
    }
}
```

Although to make maintenance easier

1. Rename `daysleaveleft` to `getLeaveDaysLeft` or something that describes the function better.
2. Move the `getLeaveDaysLeft` function into the employee model where it should actually be. This will also remove the need to pass in an id as you can use `$this->id`
3. Ensure that your `Leave` model has a relation to employee.

This will change your validator function to:

```
public function validateLeaveDaysLeft($attribute) {
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($this->startdate));
    $maxLeaveDays = $this->employee->getLeaveDaysLeft($year);
    if ($this->$attribute < $maxLeaveDays) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Maximum Quota is Exceeded,Cannot Input');
    }
}
```